# assembly code with MOVS

Tags: assembly, x86

As a beginner with assembly code, I'm confused with the movs. The resulting contents of the nine bytes starting at y would be (’a’,’b’,’c’,’a’,’b’,’c’,’a’,’b’,’c’), but i don't know why. I know movs is to copy from one memory to another, but how does the following code work?

```
1 .data
2    x: .string "abcde" # 5 characters plus a null
3    y: .space 9
4
5 .text
6 .globl _start
7 _start:
8    movl $x, %esi              #esi point to x as source
9    movl %esi, %edi            #edi point to x as destination
10   addl $3, %edi              #why we add 3 to edi?
11   movl $6, %ecx              #counter
12   rep movsb                  #what does it exactly do?
13 done:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How the instructions work is written in the instruction set reference.

> addl $3, %edi              #why we add 3 to edi?

That adjusts the destination address so it points to the 4th character.

> rep movsb                  #what does it exactly do?

Performs `ecx` iterations, each time copying a byte from `[ds:esi]` to `[es:edi]` and incrementing both by one (assuming direction flag is clear, which it normally is).

As such, that code is equivalent to:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++) x[i + 3] = x[i];
```

This will of course copy 6 characters starting from the beginning of the string over itself offset by 3. However when `i >= 3` it will read bytes already copied:

```
1. abcae
2. abcab
3. abcabc
4. abcabca
5. abcabcab
6. abcabcabc
```

Answer (score 2):

Intel's manual is linked from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  You will find an exact and detailed description of everything that `movsb` does.  The direction of pointer increments depends on the "direction" flag, but the common ABIs require the direction flag to be cleared on function entry (so esi/edi are incremented, not decremented).  Unless you're writing a bootloader (that should make as few assumptions as possible about initial state), you can assume that DF is cleared unless you set it yourself.

Overlapping source and dest will produce something like this.  Instead of reading a `d`, the 4th byte read is an `a` that was written as the first byte.  The `add $3, %edi` obviously sets the destination to `x+3`, I guess to demonstrate an overlapping copy.  Better code would have been to replace the `mov/add` pair with one `lea 3(%esi), %edi` insn.

Are you sure that `abcabcabc` is what you found at `y`?  That's exactly what you should find at `x`, with the trailing zero-byte being one that was originally there in `y` (not one that `movs` copied).

---

Even though `rep movs`'s microcode implementation will use 64bit loads/stores for high performance, it does still handle the special case of closely-overlapping src and dest.  (IDK about performance in this case.  It might fall back to a slower version, or figure out the repeated pattern and sort of `stos` that.)

Comment: Good catch on the dest being `x`, rather than `y`.

Comment: The result is what book says. I'm not sure if the book is right or wrong.

Comment: The book is wrong, the 9 bytes at `y` would just be the last `abc` and 6 bytes of zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

All x86 instructions are described in [Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), so I suggest that you download them.

The description for `MOVSB` is:

```
A4    MOVSB       For legacy mode, Move byte from address
                  DS:(E)SI to ES:(E)DI. For 64-bit mode move
                  byte from address (R|E)SI to (R|E)DI.
```

With the following operation pseudo-code:

```
DEST ← SRC;

IF (Byte move)
  THEN IF DF = 0
    THEN
      (E)SI ← (E)SI + 1;
      (E)DI ← (E)DI + 1;
    ELSE
      (E)SI ← (E)SI – 1;
      (E)DI ← (E)DI – 1;
    FI;
...
```

And the `REP` prefix simply means:

> Repeats a string instruction the number of times specified in the count register.

The count register in this case is `ecx`.

Comment: As the only person to have mentioned the dependence on the value of the Direction-flag, your answer seems a little unloved. Yours is a vitally important observation, imho.

Answer (score 1):

Run it in a debugger and see!

Basically, esi (source) and edi (dest) both point to the `.string` variable.Then edi is set to point to 3 chars past the start of the string, that is it points to the memory that holds 'd'. 
At this point the following is executed 6 times (in the form of the `rep movsb`)

- mov 1 byte from [esi] to [edi]
- increment esi
- increment edi

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Michael - whether ESI and EDI are incremented or decremented depends on the direction-flag. If it is (already) set, the registers are decremented. /edit

So, the destination is 3 bytes in front of the source at all times. Therefore, after 3 bytes have been copied, the source now points to where the dest was before the `rep movsb` instruction started.

Comment: As the only person to have mentioned running it in a debugger, your answer seems a little unloved.  :D  For the record, I also mentioned the direction flag.

Comment: As long as its 6 times, it should be abcabc instead of abcabcabc, right?

Comment: @Wiiiii - not quite. You're forgetting to account for the fact that the destination is 3 bytes in front of the source. Therefore, you get the first 3 bytes 'abc' and then another 6 more 'abcabc'. Running this type of exercise in a debugger is a useful expenditure of time.